# alchemy websockets infinite timeout

Tags: websocket, timeout

I've set up a websockets server using the Alchemy library for stress testing a websockets client. This implements a fire-hose scenario to simulate an existing system where the server sends messages, but the client does NOT... ever.

Everything is working quite well short of one issue...  extending the timeout.

I need to let the server run for days; 7, 14 or even 30. The sample code shows how to set hours, minutes and seconds:

TimeOut = new TimeSpan(hh,mm,ss)

I'd like an infinite timeout if possible, or at least be able to run it for up to 30 days.

I've looked thru the docs, and it doesn't address the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: The TimeOut doesn't do anything anyway.  See here https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets/issues/85

Answer (score 0):

According this doc http://alchemywebsockets.net/docs/class_alchemy_1_1_web_socket_server.html#a4c54ee41aa902b35f0b340adbf85c5ec
timeout happends when socket doesn't receive anything for time more than timeout value.

Maximum allowed value for timeout is **TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Int32.MaxValue-1)** that is about **24 days**.

If you want to be sure that timout did not happen you can implement own ping-pong methods.